# add-in to open automatically "data frame properties

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, data-frame

How can  created an ArcMap Python add-in using ArcGIS 10.1 to open  automatically data frame properties And change the background color of another?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way you could do this with arcpy. The DataFrame object you will work with doesn't have a property for the color of the data frame exposed. See full list of supported methods and properties [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000003000000).

You will need to use [ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/) to extend ArcMap or write a custom [add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/). See the [Developing with ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS/01w200000002000000/) Help section.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer,Do you know of a command / script in Python that allows change the background color of MXD?

Comment: @Sivan, as far as I know, this is not reachable from Python in ArcGIS and thus there are no scripts that could do that without you going into the Data Frame properties (or using ArcObjects). This is because the map document background is always defined based on the active data frame background color.